# How to call Controller from another folder via url Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, controller

I have this folder structure (symfony 2 application):

```
src
|-- Application
|   |-- UserBundle
|   |   |-- Admin
|   |   |-- Api
|   |       |-- SomeController.php
|   |   |-- Controller
|   |       |-- DefaultController.php
|   |   |-- DependencyInjection
|   |   |-- Entity
|   |   |-- Resources
|   |   |-- Tests
```

I want to call some controller from Api folder. How i can do this?

UPD.

I use symfony routing to provide the controller:

```
application_homepage:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: ApplicationUserBundle:Default:index }

application_some:
    path:     /api/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: ApplicationUserBundle:../Api/Some:index }
```

I want to load controller from Api folder

Comment: Please provide the code to show what you have attempted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the namespace of your controller is : `Application\UserBundle\Api`,
that the className is `SomeController` and the action is `indexAction`

You can use this syntax in your routing file :

```
application_some:
    path:     /api/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: Application\UserBundle\Api\SomeController::indexAction }
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work too:

```
application_some:
    resource: "@ApplicationUserBundle/Api"
    type: annotation
```

or:

```
application_some:
    resource: "@ApplicationUserBundle/Api/SomeController.php"
    type: annotation
```

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#including-external-routing-resources

Answer (score 0):

If both controller sit within the same namespace, you could simply do

```
$controller = new ControllerInApiFolder();
$conotroller->someFunction();
```

if they do not, then you need to include the controller via use-statement.

```
use Namespace\My\Controller\Sits\In\ControllerInApiFolder;
```

If you are trying to access the controller not from another controller, but from a template, an url or a testcase, you should refer to the symfony2 documentation.

[Symfony2 Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html)

From the edited question above I take it you want to call the controller via the url. 
In your browser you can simply type in

```
path/to/my/web/api/something
```

or

```
path/to/my/web/app_dev.php/api/something
```

where "path/to/my/web" referes to the path of the web folder within your project

EDIT: I think now I am getting the problem...
Symfony2 routing always defaults to the /Controller folder to look for the controller (which is quite nice).

I am not quite sure you should add another folder to this. Instead, the documentation suggests having multiple folders inside the /Controller folder.
If you take a look at the folder structure displayed here: [Symfony2 Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html), you will notice that there is an API folder within the /Controller folder.

```
<your-project>/
├─ ...
└─ src/
   └─ AppBundle/
      ├─ ...
      └─ Controller/
         ├─ DefaultController.php
         ├─ ...
         ├─ Api/
         │  ├─ ...
         │  └─ ...
         └─ Backend/
            ├─ ...
            └─ ...
```

Comment: Yes, i want to call the controller via url. But i want to call controller from Api folder, not Controller folder.